# How to resolve net framework confict in user control

Tags: .net, frameworks, controls

Visual Sudio 2022:
I am creating a user control. I have selected the Windows Forms Class Library template but it only allows me to use ".Net 3.1", ".Net 5.0" or ".net 6.0".
The application that will use the control is built with "Net Framework 4.7.2". When I Build the solution I get a message saying "Project '..\xxx\xxx.vbproj' targets 'net6.0-windows'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.
(I am not offered a target framework of "Net 6.0" in the consuming project, despite having installed it)

How do I resolve the conflict?

Comment: You should use a template with **.NET Framework** in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Luksaz. I just didn't see the .Net Framework option in the project options